# Screen is not moving up while entering text in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I enter text in the EditText in my emulator, the screen is not moving up so I cannot see what I am inputting.

I wanted to attach screenshots, but I don't have the required reputation yet.

This is a problem only with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recQsEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recAnsEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/recQsEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="@string/recoveryInfo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recQsEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recQsEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:text="@string/recoveryAnsText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setRecQsBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recAnsEditText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="@string/saveChangesBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Meanwhile, it is working fine in another screen on the same app.

The working code is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addUserIdEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addTitleEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:maxLines="1" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addUserIdEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addTitleEditText"
    android:text="@string/userIdInputText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addUserIdEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addUserIdEditText"
    android:text="@string/passwordInputText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/titleInputText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addUserIdEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addPasswordEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addPasswordEditText"
    android:text="@string/loginURLinputText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addLoginUrlEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addOtherNotesEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addLoginUrlEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addLoginUrlEditText"
    android:text="@string/otherNotesInputText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addOtherNotesEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:onClick="saveOnClick"
    android:text="@string/saveBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm struggling to figure out why it isn't working. Please help!

Comment: what is the windowSoftInputMode value in the manifest of your activity ?

Comment: I haven't set any windowSoftInputMode in my manifest...and it hasn't got self generated either.

Comment: But it works for the all screens in my app except one...That's whats confusing me!

Comment: this is the parameter that defines how your screen readjusts itself when you open the soft keyboard. it recommend you check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest file,

add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to your activity class.

example:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

This will bring editText properly adjusted to soft keyboard. check out other options in it to suit your needs.